# Eclipse keeps marking web.xml as erroneous

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0) on a Windows 11 system for developing Java web apps.

The client uses a very old version of JBoss 5 with JDK 1.6. They keep scheduling and postponing an upgrade as multiple applications would need to be upgraded.

In my project facets, I have set "Dynamic Web Module" to 2.2 and "Java" to 1.6 to be able to deploy for that server.

Each time I open web.xml for editing, Eclipse marks it as containing errors. The first line (below) is marked. The message is: `There is '1' error in 'http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/j2ee/j2ee_1_4.xsd'.`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
          version="2.4">
```

If I delete all the attributes and undo the deletion, the error goes away.

What is causing this?

Comment: Eclipse 2022-03 is two releases behind. Please make sure to ask questions only about the current version. Please also tell with which editor you opened the file and if it also applies to other editors (right-click + _Open With > ..._).

Comment: Sounds vaguely like https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1137, especially if it appears only when opening the file. In any case, your first action should be to get onto the current release.

Comment: Right ho. Shall upgrade post haste.